# How can I deploy multiple flask apps on the same gcp project?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to deploy multiple apps on the same project. I am using
`gcloud app deploy app.yaml     --project <project name>` to deploy from the folder where everything is for each app, but it's just overwriting in the same url each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [App Engine service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/an-overview-of-app-engine) is the solution, you can create a multiple service in App Engine to serve your multiple application. To do this you need to deploy your application with the line of `service` and the name of your service in your `app.yaml`, for example:

**app.yaml:**

```
service: second-app
runtime: python39
```

then redeploy:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

You can find your App Engine service app URL in this [App Engine > Services](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/services) or the like the format below:

```
https://SERVICE_ID-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com
```

Comment: You can also do it with a single service.  Map multiple domains to the service and then route the URLs by domain.

Comment: Thank you John! This is the best and simplest answer I've seen on this issue! Took me a minute to implement.